# Analysis and control of systems with different sampling frequency and control frequency

Tags: control, control-system

Now I have a discrete-time system
\begin{align}
x(k+1) =& Ax(k) + Bu(k) \\
y(k) = & Cx(k). 
\end{align}
sampled at time kT where k=0, 1, 2, ... Due to some physical constraint, the interval T cannot be extended. Meanwhile, the control input u(k) is updated every mT seconds, where m>1 is an integer.

I wonder how we can analyze this kind of system, such as its stability, or design control laws. Can anyone introduce related typical methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you're doing subsampling in the controller, going from sampling at \$t = Tk\$ to \$t = mTn\$, where \$n\$ is a new sample index.  I'm assuming that you're not only driving \$u\$ at time \$mTn\$, but that's the only time you're sampling \$y\$.

If you work this out, you'll see that for any period of samples \$k\$ where \$u(k)\$ is constant, \$x(k)\$ evolves as

$$ \begin{align}
x(k) &= A x(k-1) + B u(k-1) \\
     &= A^2 x(k-2) + AB u(k-2) + B u(k-1) \\
     &= A^3 x(k-3) + A^2 B u(k-3) + ABu(k-2) + Bu(k-1) \\
     & \cdots
\end{align}$$

So for your new subsampled system, your new state space system is:

$$\begin{align}
x(n) &= A^m x(n-1) + \left ( \sum_{p=0}^{m-1} A^p B \right )u(n-1) \\
y(n) &= C x(n)
\end{align}$$

So let \$ A_s = A^m\$ and \$B_s = \sum_{p=0}^{m-1} A^p B \$, and do your stability analysis on that.

Note that you can get the same result by making the following matrix:

$$K = \begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
A & B \\
\hline
0 & I
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix},
$$

then raise it to the \$m^{th}\$ power (any decent math package will do this).  The result will be

$$K^m = \begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
A^m & \sum_{p=0}^{m-1} A^p B \\
\hline
0 & I
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Then you can extract your \$A_s\$ and \$B_s\$ matrices, and have fun.

---

Note that you can do a similar thing going from continuous-time to sampled time -- it's just that in this case you're finding the solution to a differential equation instead of a difference equation.

With *no proof whatsoever*, you're finding

$$\begin{aligned}
A_T &= e^{AT} \\
B_T &= \left ( \int_0^T e^{AT} dt \right )B
\end{aligned}$$

The second line of this has difficulties when \$A\$ is singular, but you can find them both as

$$K_T = \begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
e^{A T} & \sum_{p=0}^{m-1} A^p B \\
\hline
0 & I
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix} = e^{KT},
$$
where \$K\$ is defined as
$$
K = \begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
A &  B \\
\hline
0 & 0
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

I'd love to direct you to a demonstration of this -- I found it in the guts of a Matlab function.  It's basically the solution to the differential equation that you get when you set u(t) to a constant value in the interval \$t_0 - T < t < t_0\$.

Comment: What a great answer, I've wondered about this before